Where did Tolstoy write that a man is like a fraction?
Leo Tolstoy allegedly wrote “A man is like a fraction whose numerator is what he is and whose denominator is what he thinks of himself. The larger the denominator, the smaller the fraction.” If so, where did he write it?

I found an answer to this in a surprising-but-perhaps-not-so-surprising source, the Mathematical Association of America.

I have received your letter, Dimitri Yegorovich, and thank you for it. I perfectly agree with you that humility is the greatest and most needful virtue. As I always say, man is like a fraction, in which the denominator indicates his opinion about himself. It is best for this denominator to be zero (complete humility), and it is terrible when it is augmented to infinity. In the first case, man has a true significance, whatever the denominator; but in the second case — none.

The above quote is from a letter to a priest (Father Dimitri Yegorovich Troitsky) dated 5 November 1910 (just 15 days before Tolstoy's death), more context of which can be found here.
The exact quote that you're asking about seems to have first appeared in Return to Mathematical Circles by Howard W. Eves, but according to Michael Molinsky who wrote the MAA article linked at the beginning of this answer:

Unfortunately, Eves provided no information on the original source of the quotation, and I have found no publication before 1988 that contains the same wording that Eves provides.


A walking zero division error, eh, Leo? Perhaps a denominator of 1 would mean having a true opinion of yourself — your numerator converted identically into the fraction :)

@LukeSawczak I agree. Tolstoy apparently doesn't understand fractions if he thinks a denominator of zero means humility. It would mean an ego of infinite size.

@Wastrel Well, rather, he sees the denominator as the ego and the quotient as the measure of the man, or something like that. A denominator of zero would mean a quotient of infinite (or undefined) size, but no ego at all.

The intent is clear, but there is an apparent flub in the quote. Seems it should be "In the first case, man has a true significance, whatever the numerator", ie dividing by zero gives infinity regardless of the numerator (unless this too is zero).

Said another way, the worth of a man is inversely proportional to his ego. Still working on a formula for women that wont get me slapped.

To supplement Rand al’Thor’s excellent answer, the original letter from Tolstoy to Troitsky can be read here (all Tolstoy’s letters of 1910, hosted online at the Faculty of Journalism of Moscow State University).  The letter is #273 on that page, dated October 23 (presumably of the Julian calendar used in Tsarist Russia, corresponding to Nov 5 in the modern Gregorian calendar).  The original quotation itself is:

Получил ваше доброе письмо, Дмитрий Егорович, и благодарю за него. Совершенно согласен с тем, что смирение есть величайшая и необходимая добродетель.  Как я всегда говорю, человек подобен дроби, в которой знаменатель определяет его мнение о самом себе. Самое лучшее, когда знаменатель этот ноль (полное смирение), а ужасно, когда знаменатель этот возрастает до бесконечности. В первом случае, каков бы ни был знаменатель, он имеет действительное значение, во втором же случае — никакого.

The translation by Molinsky quoted in Rand al’Thor’s answer is generally very faithful, as far as I can judge from my rudimentary Russian.
The original can also be found in print on p.203 of Vol. 82 Letters 1910 (May–November) of the 1928–58 Complete Collected Works of Tolstoy (whose interesting history is discussed in detail here).

Many thanks, Peter, and my compliments to your Russian proficiency! You impressed me, again! Happy holidays to you, in Sweden, I presume, and my respects!

@FrodeAlfsonBjørdal I hadn’t realised the question was from you!  Happy holidays likewise — from Australia in fact, with family.
